# Getting some errors whilst checking dirnames for spaces

Tags: shell

I've managed to cobble up this script to identify if directory_names contain spaces at the end of start. however I'm getting errors and I don't know enough about shell scripting to fix it.

```
check_directory_names() {
    local invalid_dirs=()
    while IFS=read -r -d '' dir; do
        if [[ "$dir" =~ \ ]]; then
            invalid_dirs+=("$dir")
        fi
    done < <(find . -type d -print0)
    
    if [ ${#invalid_dirs[@]} - ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Directories with spaces detected:"
    printf '%s\n' "${invalid_dirs[@]}"
    return 1
    fi
}
```

the error I've got is as follows

> ```
> line 7: syntax error in conditional expression: unexpected token `;'
> line 7: syntax error near `;'
> line 7: `        if [[ "$dir" =~ \ ]]; then'
> ```

Comment: `IFS=read` doesn’t look quite right.

Comment: `[[ ...` is not valid in a POSIX shell.

Comment: wouldn't `find $baseDirForchecking -type d -name '* *'` find your bad dirnames?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Not that the script doesn't work, it does.
But, the one-liner wins every time.
Thanks goes to: https://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter
`find $baseDirForchecking -type d -name '* *'`

---

The regular expression in the if statement's \ character is being interpreted as an escape character, causing the syntax error.

Use a different escape character, like backslash, to escape the space character.

```
check_directory_names() {
    local invalid_dirs=()
    while IFS=read -r -d '' dir; do
        if [[ "$dir" =~ \\ ]]; then
            invalid_dirs+=("$dir")
        fi
    done < <(find . -type d -print0)
    
    if [ ${#invalid_dirs[@]} -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Directories with spaces detected:"
        printf '%s\n' "${invalid_dirs[@]}"
        return 1
    fi
}
```